# Cast List<object> to unknown T[] using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I found something similar on another question but i couldnt solve my problem as i'm still quite new in c#.

i have

```
System.Type type; // for example int[]
System.Type elementType = type.GetElementType(); //for example int
```

and a List that i need to cast to int[]

```
object valueObj; //is my List<object> i want to cast to int[]
```

I'm trying the following:

```
MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast")
    .MakeGenericMethod( new System.Type[]{ elementType } );
MethodInfo toArrayMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray")
     .MakeGenericMethod( new System.Type[]{ elementType } );

var castedObjectEnum = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { valueObj });
var castedObject = toArrayMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { castedObjectEnum });
```

in the last line i get this runtime exception

InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator0`1[System.Int32].MoveNext ()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable)

as a last thing i need to assign the casteObject to a privateField using

```
field.SetValue(this, castedObject);
```

Edit:
I will try and get more info on that but to better explain what i'm trying to do i will explain the use case.

i serialize to disk in json some class fields, and then when i deserialize i get back a List where i serialize a base array of int/bools/string

I'm doing the serialization and deserialization by marking fields with a custom attribute, and i want to be able to serialize both Array and Lists of any basic type

i will double check and get with more info

Comment: Rather than posting *snippets* of the broken code, please work this into a short but complete console app demonstrating the problem. It will make it *much* easier for other people to help you.

Comment: Are they actually all int's? Are they something which you could *convert* to an int? Why do you not know the actual types at this point in the code? Reflection should be rarely needed, so the answers to all of these will help answer your question.

Comment: i dont know the type, i added a bit of explanation on the use case. @jonSkeet, i will double check and try to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing wrong.

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates, and it seems it uses the same calls that you do, yet I do get an output of the right type of array.

```
void Main()
{
    object valueObj = new List<object> { 1, 2, 3 };
    Type type = typeof(int[]);

    Type elementType = type.GetElementType();
    MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast")
        .MakeGenericMethod( new System.Type[]{ elementType } );
    MethodInfo toArrayMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray")
        .MakeGenericMethod( new System.Type[]{ elementType } );

    var castedObjectEnum = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { valueObj });
    var castedObject = toArrayMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { castedObjectEnum });
    castedObject.Dump();
}
```

I *do* get an output corresponding to an array of int's. The code as posted seems to work just fine. Your problem must be elsewhere. Could it be that you're not actually sending in a property `List<object>` or that the list contains something that isn't an int?

Just changing this line:

```
object valueObj = new List<object> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

to this:

```
object valueObj = new List<object> { 1, 2, 3, "Test" };
```

Gives me that exception.

Perhaps you want `OfType` instead of `Cast`?

If you replace the string in the `castMethod` retrieval, it again "works", but of course it will filter away that string.

More information is needed here.

Comment: you are right, there is something wrong with my valueObj. the type is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object] and looping all objects and Convert.ToInt32 (there are just three 0s). but thanks i will investigate in that direction now what's wrong

Comment: in this case i had the List<System.Int64> thats why it was not working. i will see what i need to adjust to cover this case

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you have the source `List<object>` and can get the length of it.

You could call [Array.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx) with your type and the length.  Then all you have to do is move the items over one by one.

Why use linq for this?